# HDR stacking of images in halcon

Tags: hdr, halcon

I have multiple images that I have to merge to a single HDR image in Halcon.

I've been looking online and in the manual, but was not able to find any HDR comand..
How can this be done in Halcon?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the example program "create_high_dynamic_range_image.dev".

I can't remember which version this was released in. If it is not in your version then get a trial license of the newest version of Halcon and test it out.

[image]